# Team Foundation Server 2013 backup completes successfully but not saving any .BAK and .TRN files

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, team-foundation-server

I just encountered this issue with my production TFS server, which was backing up normally for the last few years.

Backups have just stopped saving any other files except these 2. Also, there are  no errors. 
- BackupSets.xml
- BackupSettings.xml

My issue is exactly the same as 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e920100-36bf-49cb-affb-fdf5d03deef4/tfs-2013-why-is-full-backup-failing-to-make-bak-files

Has anyone encountered this kind of behavior with TFS backups?

I have already tried the following:
1. Restarted server couple of times
2. Re-created backup plans
3. Run Full Backup manually (multiple times)
4. Checked User / Folder permissions (nothing has changed)